# Renovate does not automerge with gitea

Tags: gitea, renovate

Unfortunately, automerge of minor and patch versions does not work, although I have set Renovate to do so.
The branch has the status yellow (see log below). However, it is not clear why this is the case. The log below states "Branch cache not found, creating minimal branchState". Can this be the cause?
Why isn't cache found? I set

```
export RENOVATE_BASE_DIR="/renovate"
```

And there is the cache directory as expected.

I use Gitea 1.20.5 and Renovate 37.34.0 (self hosted).

The branch has tests that all run without errors.
The Gitea user has the rights
Repository and organization access: All (public, private and limited):

```
write:activitypub
write:misc
write:notification
write:organization
write:package
write:issue
write:repository
write:user
```

Renovate runs every hour triggered by Jenkins.

My Renovate configuration:

```
{
  "platform": "gitea",
  "endpoint": "https://myGitea/api/v1/",
  "token": "myToken",
  "branchPrefix": "renovate.",
  "logFile": "/renovate/renovate.log",
  "logFileLevel": "debug",
  "extends": [ "config:recommended"],
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "matchHost": "myRepo",
      "token": "myToken"
    }
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["maven"],
      "registryUrls": [
        "https://myRepo/artifactory/release"
      ]
    },
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch"],
      "matchCurrentVersion": "!/^0/",
      "automerge": true
    }
  ],
  "platformAutomerge": true,
  "repositories": [
    "myRepo"
  ]
}
```

The relevant log:

```
DEBUG: syncBranchState() (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: syncBranchState(): Branch cache not found, creating minimal branchState (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: getBranchPr(renovate.jackson_version) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: findPr(renovate.jackson_version, undefined, open) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Found PR #456 (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Returning from cached PRs (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branchExists=true (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: dependencyDashboardCheck=undefined (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: PR rebase requested=false (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Check for closed PR because recreating closed PRs is disabled. (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: findPr(renovate.jackson_version, fix(deps): update jackson_version to v2.15.3, !open) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: findPr(renovate/jackson_version, fix(deps): update jackson_version to v2.15.3, !open) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: prAlreadyExisted=false (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Checking if PR has been edited (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branch.isModified(): using git to calculate (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branch.isModified() = false (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Found existing branch PR (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Checking schedule(at any time, null) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: No schedule defined (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Branch already exists (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branch.isBehindBase(): using git to calculate (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branch.isBehindBase(): false (repository=myRepo, baseBranch=master, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
       "branchName": "renovate.jackson_version"
DEBUG: Branch is up-to-date (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: isBranchConflicted(master, renovate.jackson_version) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branch.isConflicted(): using git to calculate (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: branch.isConflicted(): false (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Branch does not need rebasing (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Using reuseExistingBranch: true (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Setting current branch to master (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: latest commit (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
       "branchName": "master",
       "latestCommitDate": "2023-11-09T21:30:52+01:00"
DEBUG: manager.getUpdatedPackageFiles() reuseExistingBranch=true (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: No package files need updating (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Getting updated lock files (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Writing package.json files (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
       "packageFiles": ["frontend/package.json"]
DEBUG: Writing frontend/package-lock.json (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Writing any updated package files (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: No updated lock files in branch (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: No files to commit (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Setting current branch to master (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: latest commit (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
       "branchName": "master",
       "latestCommitDate": "2023-11-09T21:30:52+01:00"
DEBUG: Checking if we can automerge branch (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: mergeStatus=no automerge (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Ensuring PR (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: There are 0 errors and 0 warnings (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: getBranchPr(renovate.jackson_version) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: findPr(renovate.jackson_version, undefined, open) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Found PR #456 (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Returning from cached PRs (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: getPrCache() (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Found existing PR (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Fetching changelog: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8 (2.13.4 -> 2.15.3) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Fetching changelog: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers (2.13.4 -> 2.15.3) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Fetching changelog: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations (2.13.4 -> 2.15.3) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Fetching changelog: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core (2.13.4 -> 2.15.3) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Processing existing PR (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: resolveBranchStatus(branchName=renovate.jackson_version, ignoreTests=false) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Branch status check result (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
       "ccs": {"worstStatus": "unknown", "statuses": []}
DEBUG: Branch status yellow (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: setPrCache() (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Pull Request #456 does not need updating (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: PR is configured for automerge (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: checking auto-merge (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Checking schedule(at any time, null) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: No schedule defined (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: resolveBranchStatus(branchName=renovate.jackson_version, ignoreTests=false) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: Branch status check result (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
       "ccs": {"worstStatus": "unknown", "statuses": []}
DEBUG: Branch status yellow (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
DEBUG: PR is not ready for merge (branch status is yellow) (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)
```

Comment: could it be something as silly as branch protection rules?

Comment: its a bug, get back to Renovate's GitHub repository and ask them for details

Answer (score 0):

`DEBUG: Branch status yellow (repository=myRepo, branch=renovate.jackson_version)`

It seems that Renovate has the branch status as yellow, based on the CSS status check.

Check the status checks and ensure the checks on the `renovate.jackson_version` are passed.

I don't know if this can help you, but it's my response.

Comment: What is "CSS status check"?